# App to select random objects from photo

Tags: android, photography

I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum to post or the wrong format of the question.

I am looking for an Android app that can take a picture from the camera and then place random markers (say 20) on the picture (ideally numbered 1..20). The app has to work offline.

Here is what the app is needed for. A scientists walks around a field of plants and at several places needs to select ten random plants from a square meter for sampling. He would point his camera at an area of size roughly 1 sqm and take the plants at markers 1..10. In the case that two markers are on the same plant, marker 11 is taken and so on.

Does something like this exist or can something like this be done with an existing image processing app?

Comment: How many plants do you see in this picture? https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lion_in_jungle_under_tree.jpg Could you please give us an example picture of what you imagine? Will it always be plants, or could it be any imaginable object (which is more difficult)

Comment: I'll try to dig out an image. Essentially, it would be enough to just place random, numbered points on an image and the scientist could just go through them in incrementing order and remove duplicates using the built-in wetware.

Comment: Oh, so no image recognition is needed, I see. That makes the app much more realistically implementable :-) By the way, by wetware do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetware_(biology)?

Comment: Statistically speaking, I don't think this strategy will do what you want. I mean, I presume you want an equal probability of selecting each of the distinct plants growing within a square meter, but if you choose random pixels of an image and then sample the plants that occupy those pixels, you'll be more likely to sample plants that take up more of the image (because e.g. they're simply bigger plants). Getting uniform sampling seems to require counting all the plants first, so you can given them ID numbers and then randomly sample from the ID numbers.